# Sum of the numbers 1 to 1000 in parallel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

The following code uses `2n` CPUs to calculate the sum of `1` to `1000`. Each of the processors calculates a portion of this aggregate and independently displays the output.

The final result of the computing of all processors is collected by the first processor and aggregated and the final result is displayed in the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

static int MyNode, Nodes;
using namespace std;
int main(int* argc, char** argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(argc, argv);
    MyNode = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyNode);
    Nodes =  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Nodes);
    MPI_Status status;
    int sum = 0;
    int accum = 0;
    int FIndex = 1000 * MyNode / Nodes + 1;
    int LIndex = 1000 * (MyNode + 1) /
        Nodes;
    for (int I = FIndex; I <= LIndex; I = I + 1)
        sum += I;
    if (MyNode != 0)
        MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else
        for (int J = 1; J < Nodes; J = J + 1) {
            MPI_Recv(&accum, 1, MPI_INT,
                J, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                &status);
            sum += accum;
        }
    if (MyNode == 0) {
        cout << "Total Nodes is " << Nodes << ".The sum from 1 to 1000 is: " << sum << endl;
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

After running, I encounter a problem: `Integer division by zero.` (MyNode / Nodes)

why `MyNode` , `Nodes` are zero?

Comment: What does the documentation say about what MPI_Comm_size returns?

Comment: I rolled your code back to the original so the answers make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass reference to `MyNode` and `Nodes`:

```
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyNode);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Nodes);
```

> MPI_Comm_size returns MPI_SUCCESS on success. Otherwise, the return
>   value is an error code.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200986/try-to-convert-c-program-to-mpi-program-but-error-occur   code

Answer (score 1):

The following functions return errors if any

```
MyNode = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyNode);
Nodes =  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Nodes);
```

Since you are storing the error state in MyNode and Nodes, (In this case there is no error) The value of MyNOde and Nodes is 0.

Change it to this

```
int err;
err = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyNode);
err =  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Nodes);
```

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200986/try-to-convert-c-program-to-mpi-program-but-error-occur code?